# Subdeterminant inequality for positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $C$ be a real positive definite matrix. Let $C_{i,j}$ denote the matrix we obtain by deleting the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column from $C$. I'd like to know if the following determinant inequality holds:

$$|C_{i,j}|^2 \leq |C_{i,i}||C_{j,j}|$$

I've checked a few hundred random examples, and haven't found a counterexample -- hopefully, this result is somewhere out there, if true.

Comment: This is simply because $C^{-1}$ is positive definite whenever $C$ is positive definite.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The minors are (up to a sign) directly proportional to the elements of $C^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, got it!